# Why do CompositionalLayout estimated sizes get turned into fixed constraints?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout

My compositional layout is largely working as intended, with the exception that estimated sizes are being turned into fixed constraints. I want the layout to accommodate the current dynamic type sizing and adapt to changes in it.

If the estimated size is smaller than the initially required size the layout looks broken and there are over-constrained view warnings. If the estimated size is larger than required, the view doesn't shrink to fit.

The image view is constrained as follows:

- leading, top, trailing to cell's `.contentView`
- aspect ratio to 16:9
- bottom to top of label with a spacing of 10pt

The label's constraints:

- leading, bottom, trailing to cell's `.contentView`

The label's font is set via `.preferredFont(forTextStyle:compatibleWith:)`

The label has `.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true`

Adjusting the font size from device Settings takes immediate effect, as expected, in regard to the text size changing and the label frame adjusting. But the estimated size has been turned into a fixed constant constraint, so the view as a whole does not resize as intended/expected.

Appearance with an estimated size larger than required:

[image: Screenshot depicting expected layout]

Setting the estimated size too small results in the label disappearing from view. Whatever value of `N` is passed as the size estimate, it is turned into a seemingly fixed `UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height: view-height: = N @ 1000` constraint.

From a new iOS app, replacing the entire content of the default `ViewController.swift` with the code below demonstrates the problem:

(change the values in `makeLayout()` to see the different outcomes)

```
import UIKit

struct Model: Hashable {
    let title: String
}

class ImageAndLabelCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    let imageView: UIImageView = {
        let view = UIImageView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.backgroundColor = .blue
        return view
    }()

    let label: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.font = .preferredFont(forTextStyle: .subheadline, compatibleWith: .current)
        label.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true
        return label
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        setup()
    }

    func setup() {
        contentView.addSubview(imageView)
        contentView.addSubview(label)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            imageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor),
            imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor),
            imageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor),
            imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 9/16),

            label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.bottomAnchor, constant: 10),
            label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor),
            label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor),
            label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor)
        ])
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    private let collection = UICollectionView(frame: .zero,
                                              collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setup()
    }

    private var models = [
        Model(title: "Some text here"),
        Model(title: "Some different here"),
        Model(title: "A third model")
    ]

    private var dataSource: UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<String, Model>?

    func setup() {
        collection.register(ImageAndLabelCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")

        collection.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(collection)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            collection.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            collection.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            collection.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            collection.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
        ])

        dataSource = UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<String, Model>(collectionView: collection, cellProvider: { collectionView, indexPath, itemIdentifier in
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
            if let cell = cell as? ImageAndLabelCell {
                cell.label.text = self.models[indexPath.row].title
            }
            return cell
        })

        collection.dataSource = dataSource

        dataSource?.apply(currentSnapshot(), animatingDifferences: true)

        collection.setCollectionViewLayout(makeLayout(), animated: true)
    }

    func makeLayout() -> UICollectionViewLayout {
        return UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout { sectionIdx, environment -> NSCollectionLayoutSection? in

            let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0),
                                                  heightDimension: .estimated(50))
            let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)

            let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(0.45),
                                                   heightDimension: .estimated(50))
            let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize, subitem: item, count: 1)

            let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
            section.orthogonalScrollingBehavior = .continuous
            section.interGroupSpacing = 3

            return section
        }
    }

    func currentSnapshot() -> NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<String, Model> {
        var snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<String, Model>()

        snapshot.appendSections(["Main"])
        snapshot.appendItems(models, toSection: "Main")

        return snapshot
    }
}
```

**Update:**

Even though the group has only one item in it, switching from `.vertical(layoutSize:subItem:count:)` to `.horizontal(layoutSize:subItem:count:)` seems to have helped. The initial rendering no longer causes constraint errors, regardless of whether dynamic type was set large or small.

Changing the font size (either large to small or small to large) once the app is running results in the view trying to resize, which still causes the fixed height constraint to trigger an "Unable to simultaneously satisfy..." error.

Comment: Why not just listen for the dynamic type change and refresh the layout?

Comment: I just tried listening for `UIContentSizeCategory.didChangeNotification` and calling `self.collection.setNeedsLayout()` and `self.collection.layoutIfNeeded()`, but still see the simultaneous constraints error. Were you thinking of something slightly different?

Comment: Also tried `self.collection.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()` - a font size change while running still leads to the simultaneous constraints error.

Comment: I was thinking of reloading the data. (Not that I've tried this; just spitballing here.)

Comment: My expectation was that `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` would be the end of these sorts of manual interventions (the labels know what's happened, couldn't the cell too?). I have tried a full reload, and the console still reports a burst of simultaneous constraint errors, but I believe them to be for the outgoing cells (which are immediately replaced by newly configured/sized cells). More experimentation required to confirm this...

Comment: Actually, no, a call to `.reloadData()` has made things worse :-( With more text content in the labels and `.numberOfLines = 0` to exaggerate things, I now see cells sized to suit the _previous_ font size.

Comment: Applying a not-animated empty snapshot and then in the completion re-applying the correct snapshot does at least keep cell content and size in-sync. Lowering the priority of the constraint that the layout engine chooses to break puts an end to the errors and has no immediately apparent consequence to the layout.

Answer (score -1):

Anyone who is also struggled with this:
I set the bottom/trailing (based on you want dynamic height or dynamic width) constraint priority to 999, and it is gone.
Hope it helps.